# Angular 6+. How to extend a template adding new actions such as JSF?

Tags: angular

I'm trying to implement the concept of pages composition from JSF in Angular6 + but I have no idea how to start it. Here is what I need:

1) A template page such as search page where there are placeholders for fields, search action and search results table.

2) A page that extends template and add its fields, action and results

3) Possibility to extend # 2 and add custom actions to results data table rows.

Following picture describes each item above:

1) Search page general template

[image: Search page template]

2) Custom search page (extends #1)

[image: Custom Search Page without action]

3) Custom action added to search page (extends #2)

[image: Custom search]

3.1) Similar page to #3 but it has different action on result row (extends #2)

[image: Alternate custom page]

I want to is to standardize all the pages based on few base templates (# 1) and reuse specific pages adding new actions to it (#2). As the result, # 3 will be shown the final user and it may be used in different places with minor changes, for instance, I can search for the employee and open it OR I can lookup employee using this same search page but instead of opening its record, I will select it to fill a field from other form. In this example, all I need to do is the extend #2 and add specific action that will open or just lookup employee and set to other form.

PS: Developer may add component in placeholders.

**Updates:**

*22/11/2018*

Based on advice from Bunyamin Coskuner, I implemented a sample pretty quickly but now I'm stuck on a specific behavior.

I created a StackBlitz project and published my sample code:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-s2wkpw

Just click on "search" and take a look at the results. Action buttons are added only in last row. What is the best way to replicate these buttons in every row?

PS: Each button must pass correct parameter based on what is in the row to controller.

**I would like to ask the Angular experts if is this the best approach to archieve what I'm trying to.**

---

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is totally doable, but to answer it will take some time which is I don't have right now. I would suggest you to read about angular content projection and try to come up with a solution. If you try to implement it yourself and ask some questions along the way, people will more likely try to help you. At this moment, you haven't provided any code that you've written.

Comment: Hello @BunyaminCoskuner! Thank you for your time, actually I'm looking for a starting point and you gave me one, I'll find more info about content projection and try to implement and share some code here.

Comment: Hello @BunyaminCoskuner, added a sample code but now I'm stuck on specific issue. Could you, please, advice me what is the best way to solve it?

Comment: Alright, I'll check it out and get back to you.

Comment: Posted an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You came pretty close, I just added a directive to solve the rest. Here is the final [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v1y7gt?file=src%2Femployee-search%2Femployee-search.component.ts)

`<ng-content select="...>` works on static content projection. Sometimes, you need more powerful directive than that.

There is a little trick I got it from Angular Material codebase and use it in almost all of my components which is providing customizable templates.

Instead of writing `<ng-content select="button">` which overrides other rows of the table and only put the `button`s on the last one, you declare a directive as follows

```js
@Directive({ selector: '[appPersonSearchButtons]' })
export class TemplatePersonSearchButtonsDirective {
    constructor(public template: TemplateRef<any>) { }
}
```

This directive may not look like it is doing much and I assure you it is!
It has single property which is `template`. It is injected here because we will use this directive with `ng-template` only! If you use this directive on any other element than `ng-template` you will get an error!

You should put this directive into `declarations` array of your module

```js
declarations: [ ... TemplatePersonSearchButtonsDirective ... ]
```

Now, it is time to change `<ng-content select="button">` to something else.
First, let's make sure whether consumers of this component used this directive within their template.

I added this line to `TemplatePersonSearchComponent`

```js
@ContentChild(TemplatePersonSearchButtonsDirective) buttons: TemplatePersonSearchButtonsDirective;
```

I've changed `<tr *ngFor...>` to following

```html
<tr *ngFor="let person of persons; let i = index">
  <td width="80%">{{person}}</td>
  <td>
    <ng-container *ngIf="buttons">
      <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="buttons.template;
        context: { $implicit: person, index: i}">
      </ng-container>
    </ng-container>
  </td>
</tr>
```

`ngTemplateOutlet` is a directive that takes a `TemplateRef` as an input (which comes from `buttons.template` in this case). Also, you can pass a context too so that you can expose some data to the users (which will come in handy later).

Let's use it in our `employee-search-component`. It is pretty much the same as you wrote it, I just moved `button`s inside of an `ng-template` as follows

```html
<app-template-person-search>
  <ng-template appPersonSearchButtons let-personObj let-id="index">
    <button (click)="openPerson(personObj, id)">Open</button>
    <button (click)="deletePerson(personObj, id)">Delete</button>
  </ng-template>
</app-template-person-search>
```

Remember, we defined our context as `context: { $implicit: person, index: i}"`

Since, we defined `person` as `$implicit`, you can write anything starting with `let-` to retrieve that object. I chose `personObj` to show that you can type anything. Also, I retrieved `index` as `id` and pass these objects into a function.

```js
openPerson(person, id) {
    alert('Open ' + person + ' ' + id);
}

deletePerson(person, id) {
    alert('Delete ' + person + ' ' + id);
}
```

Comment: Very good! This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you! Now I'll move forward on my own framework and will post here case I got stuck! Have a great week!